# React, update array's total count state when new item is added to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have my array where you can add a "player" to it and it updates just fine.  I also have a *total number of players* that looks at the array and gives the total sum.  It works but it does not factor in the new items.

I know I need to pass it the new updated state of the array (players) but I'm just stuck on how to do that.

I've provided snips of my code as follows

**Array**

```
    const players = [
  {
    name: 'Jabba',
    score: 10,
    id: 11
  },
  {
    name: 'Han',
    id: 1
  },

{
    name: 'Luke',
    id: 2
  },
```

**Function to add to the array**

```
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      newPlayerName: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleAddPlayer = e => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      players: [
        ...prevState.players,
        {
          name: this.state.newPlayerName,
          id: getRandomInt(20, 155)
        }
      ]
    }));
  };
```

**my state**

```
this.state = {
  id: players.id,
  totalScore: 0,
  totalPlayers: players,
  countInfo: [],
  evilName: '',
  color: '#6E68C5',
  scoreColor: '#74D8FF',
  fontAwe: 'score-icon',
  incrementcolor: '',
  scoreNameColor: 'white',
  glow: '',
  buttonStyle: 'count-button-start',
  newPlayerName: '',
  max_chars: 15,
  chars_left: '',
  players
};
```

And finally the function that should update the total but doesn't and where I'm stuck

```
function Stats(props) {
  const totalPlayers = props.players.length;
  const totalScore = props.players.reduce(
    function(total, player) {
      return props.totalScore + props.totalScore;
    },
    0
  );
  return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <PlayerNumb>Number of players: <b>{totalPlayers}</b></PlayerNumb>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the `const totalPlayers = props.players.length;` is where I seemed to be tripped up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and apologies if I gave any confusing information as React is still new to me.

Also an example of how I called stats:

```
      <Stats
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        totalScore={this.state.totalScore}
        players={players}
      />
```

And the complete render code of how Players is created

```
render() {
    const listPlayers = this.state.players.map(player => (
      <Counter
        key={player.id}
        player={player}
        playersArray={this.state.players}
        name={player.name}
        sortableGroupDecorator={this.sortableGroupDecorator}
        decrementCountTotal={this.decrementCountTotal}
        incrementCountTotal={this.incrementCountTotal}
        removePlayer={this.removePlayer.bind(this)} //bind this to stay in the context of the parent component
        handleClick={player}
      />
    ));

    return (
      <ContainLeft style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ProjectTitle>Score Keeper</ProjectTitle>
        <Copy>
          A sortable list of players that with adjustable scores.  Warning, don't go negative!
        </Copy>
        <GroupHolder>
          <Stats
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            totalScore={this.state.totalScore}
            players={players}
          />
          <div
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            className="container"
            ref={this.sortableContainersDecorator}
          >
            <div className="group">
              <div className="group-list" ref={this.sortableGroupDecorator}>
                {listPlayers}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <HandleForm>
            <form
              style={{ width: '100%' }}
              onSubmit={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
            >
              <p className="sort-player">Add A Player</p>
              <InputText
                type="text"
                maxLength="15"
                max="4"
                name="usr"
                placeholder="Enter a new name"
                value={this.state.newPlayerName}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              <PlayerButton onClick={this.handleAddPlayer}>
                Press to Add Player
              </PlayerButton>
              <CharacterCount>
                Characters left
                {' '}
                {this.state.max_chars - this.state.newPlayerName.length}
              </CharacterCount>
            </form>
          </HandleForm>
        </GroupHolder>
      </ContainLeft>
    );
  }
}

export default Container;
```

Comment: How do you call `Stats` ?

Comment: @AndyRay I just updated it at the end of my question

Comment: Keep going. Where does `players` come from?

Comment: players comes from my array (I'm trying to work this out in my brain and thanks for not spoonfeeding me as it helps)

Comment: (not being snarky, I want to learn not be fed the answers)

Comment: so it comes from props being passed to it?

Comment: Deleted my answer since a comment works better.  Right - @Andy Ray is right. you should be able to snag this out of state since its intrinsic to having the list of players anyway. If you can pass players, you dont need to pass the total number of players. I think maybe youre mixing up totalPlayers and players in your state object?

Comment: I might, I'm rather confused and am still learning state (this is a sandbox project that I'm trying to teach myself State)

Comment: @sthig please include the code in your render function which creates the `players` variable. This question still does not have enough information to answer.

Comment: @AndyRay updated

Comment: I can add more if needed but I think that gets it for code that's stumping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling your render function with an undefined variable called `players`

```
players={players}
```

You either need to pass `this.state.players` or define it with `const players = this.state.players;`

You should always be developing locally with an eslint plugin for your editor, which will highlight problems like these as syntax errors and save you hours of time.

Comment: I am running a lint but maybe I need to update it.  I'm a little confused as to where to put this.  My players array comes from an external file `players.js` and is imported in.  

(I apologize as my React skills are rather newbie so I'm still struggling to ask questions accurately)